# My maxlength 'fix' for android, kills my 'uppercase only' data

Tags: javascript, android, input, maxlength

I have a password input on my site, which I would like to limit to 8 characters, and change the input data to all upper case characters.

The following code works great for both, except on an android device...

INPUT

```
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" class="inputField" placeholder=" Password" 
minlength="8" maxlength="8" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = ' Password'" 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter Password')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" 
required="">
```

I found this code, which does effectively limit the max input on Androids. Unfortunately... it also seems to kill the uppercase character code.

SCRIPT

```
<script>

var elInput = document.getElementById('password');
var maxLength = elInput.maxLength;
elInput.onkeyup = function(e){
if( elInput.value.length > maxLength  ){
    elInput.value = elInput.value.substring(0, maxLength);
}
};

</script>
```

Is there a way to accomplish both needs by adjusting this code?

Comment: I solved the issue with CSS: text-transform: uppercase;  And left the javascript for forcing maxlength. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elInput = document.getElementById('password');
elInput.onkeyup = function() {
  elInput.value = elInput.value.toUpperCase();
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password" maxlength="8">
```

Comment: There's no need to maintain the max number of chars in JS.

Comment: Unfortunately... your code only reverses the issue for Androids. While it will make the characters uppercase, it now kills the max length.

Comment: I solved the issue with CSS: text-transform: uppercase;  And left the javascript for forcing maxlength. Works like a charm now.